# Android: SQLite Row update causes Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, sql-update

My SQLite Row Update method causes a NullPointer Exception when trying to update a value.

```
 public void addLike(DBOps dop, String productid,String newValue,String oldValue)
 {
    try
    {
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        updatedValues.put(TableInfo.LIKED, newValue); 
        String where="pid = ?";
        updatedb.update(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,updatedValues, where, 
                                                new String[]{productid});
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", "Couldn't update likes!");
        Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause()
                                                      .getCause()));
    }
  }
```

My table name is stated in: **TableInfo.TABLE_NAME**
My column name is stated in: **TableInfo.LIKED**

Old value is retrieved by a different Get Method. The ProductID and the NewValue is not null. I checked and they contain the proper values. Is my Update method correct?

Comment: Did you checked that `updatedb` is not null ?

Comment: It is globally declared as "private SQLiteDatabase updatedb;" @sol4me

Comment: you need to initialize it. But default its null and hence nullpointer exception.

Comment: First, use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, rather than a raw `SQLiteDatabase`, unless you have a strong reason not to. Second, obtain the `SQLiteOpenHelper` via some centralized static method, where that method can initialize the `SQLiteOpenHelper` if it has not been created yet.